# How to get content of Column to wrap in react-virtualized

Tags: react-virtualized

I'm using react-virtualized to display a `Table` within an `InfiniteLoader` component.  I have multiple `Column` entries 2 of which are fixed width and one which is variable.  How can I get the variable width one to wrap instead of cutting off?  The code:

```
    <InfiniteLoader
      isRowLoaded={this.isRowLoaded}
      loadMoreRows={this.loadMoreRows}
      rowCount={99999999}
    >
      {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
        <Table
          width={this.state.width || 800}
          height={1200}
          rowCount={this.state.len}
          rowHeight={this.lineSize}
          rowGetter={this.renderItem}
        >
          <Column label='Index' dataKey='index' width={indexWidth} className='metadata'/>
          <Column label='Date' dataKey='date' width={dateWidth} className='metadata' />
          <Column label='Text' dataKey='text' width={400} flexGrow={1}/>
        </Table>
      )}
    </InfiniteLoader>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the built-in styles and default renderer for `Column` then text won't wrap. (It's set to `white-space: nowrap`.) You can either *not* use the default renderer, or not load the style-sheet, or you can override them however you want. The easiest way is probably to just provide you own [`cellRenderer`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Column.md#cellrenderer) for the `Column`.

Check out the `Table` + `CellMeasurer` [demo page](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/CellMeasurer) (source [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/CellMeasurer/CellMeasurer.DynamicHeightTableColumn.example.js)) for an example of a `Column` with wrapping text.